# autoresize gridview to displayedcells

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll

i have used below code to display data in multiline inside gridview as my cell data is long enough.

```
Grid.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
Grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

but due to this properties gridview takes too much time for loading because my database is too big.

so i did like,

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Grid.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            Grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
        }

private void Grid1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {

            Grid1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedHeaders;
            Grid1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
        }
```

but when i press page down button from keyboard,it works fine but when i scroll using mouse takes bit more time to load data and scrollbar of gridview displays abnormal.

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `AutoSizeRowsMode` you set a behavior of grid.
Instead doing it twice, in `Grid1_Scroll` event try to *perform action of adjustment*:

```
Grid1.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells);
```

You may also consider of following `Load` method:

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grid1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    Grid1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    Grid1.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
}
```

It takes time to adjust rows only once, on load.